# Regex question - searching a: specific pattern without quotes

Tags: regex

I have a MYSQL class, which I'd like to make safe against SQL injection, so I thought of a checking algorithm. For example:

```
query("SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE id = @1 AND name = '@2' AND pwd = '@3' AND somenumber = @4", param1, param2, param3, param4)
```

This regex expression must match @1 and @4, so the first, and 4th argument should be integer.

I tried this:

```
[^'"]@\d+[^'"]
```

But it doesnt match:

```
@1,@4,@5
```

What could be the right expression?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want @123 but not "@123", use

```
(?<!["'])@\d+(?!['"])
```

What your regex does:

- `[^'"]` matches one « anything but
  the string '" »
- `@\d+` matches one at sign and as
  much numbers as possible
- `[^'"]` matches another « anything
  but the string '" »

Therefore it would match d@12), @@0@, k@09. ...